# image button not showing in listview

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

I'm trying to get a delete button on my rows in my listview. however in the designer the button is showing but when debugging or running the app i cannot see it. this is my code.

adapter :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.App;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using CardAppReal.Lib.Models;
using Square.Picasso;

namespace CardAppReal.Assets
{
    public class ListAdapter : BaseAdapter<Card>
    {
        List<Card> items;
        Activity context;
        public ListAdapter(Activity context, List<Card> items)
            : base()
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.items = items;
        }
        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }
        public override Card this[int position]
        {
            get { return items[position]; }
        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get { return items.Count; }
        }
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var item = items[position];
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(NavigationDrawerTest.Resource.Layout.CardSavedRowLayout, null);
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(NavigationDrawerTest.Resource.Id.TextCardSavedList1).Text = item.name;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(NavigationDrawerTest.Resource.Id.TextCardSavedList2).Text = item.supertype;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(NavigationDrawerTest.Resource.Id.TextCardSavedList3).Text = item.set;
            Picasso.With(context).Load(item.imageUrl).Into(view.FindViewById<ImageView>(NavigationDrawerTest.Resource.Id.CardSavedImage));
            var imgButton = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(NavigationDrawerTest.Resource.Id.ImgButtonSaved);
            view.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Argb(150, 153, 217, 234));
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFDAFF7F"
    android:padding="8dp">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ImgButtonSaved"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/delete"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/TextCardList"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextCardSavedList1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FF7F3300"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextCardSavedList2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14dip"
            android:textColor="#FF267F00"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextCardSavedList3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14dip"
            android:textColor="#FF267F00"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/CardSavedImage"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

tried several things but none show. the ImageView shows normally like it is supposed to. not sure where i'm going wrong. i think it's in my adapter i need to do more then simply declare the imgbutton. but i don't know what i need to do more then that.

Comment: I assume that your `LinearLayout` overlaps your `Button`. Add a `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImgButtonSaved"` to your `LinearLayout` and see if it helps.

Comment: @Amylinn did not help. thanks though!

Comment: As a hint, check imageview by default image and remove use Picasso, may be you will get idea what's wrong.

Comment: @NitinPatel the image view works fine. its the imagebutton that is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

After Hours of looking i finaly realized i am using the wrong adapter... this was a big waste of development time. i hope that when other people read this they will double check the adapter they are using.

thanks for looking though!